# How to send only custom Header using spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have to set a custom header in the kafka message, my kafka cluster natively supports headers (1.x.x). I am currently using springCloudVersion=Finchley.RELEASE.

When I am setting property

```
default:
    producer:
      headerMode: none
```

None of the headers are coming in the output.

On the other hand, If I am setting

```
default:
    producer:
      headerMode: headers
```

Many headers including `contentType` and `spring_json_header_types` are coming in the header which greatly affects the throughput. Kafka being a language/framework agnostic message delivery mechanism, I feel, spring should provide a way to only include user-provided headers. Is there any work around to get only user-set headers to the kafka topic while suppressing all the spring cloud related headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already answered this on GitHub. It's a waste of your time and ours to ask the same question in multiple places. As I said there, Stack Overflow is the preferred place to ask questions.

Here's the answer again:

Please use Stack Overflow to ask questions; GitHub issues are for reporting bugs or asking for new features.

You can provide a custom header mapper in the [binder configuration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties).

> **spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName**
>
> The bean name of a KafkaHeaderMapper used for mapping spring-messaging headers to and from Kafka headers. Use this, for example, if you wish to customize the trusted packages in a DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper that uses JSON deserialization for the headers.
>
> Default: none.

Implement your own `KafkaHeaderMapper` and add it as a `@Bean` and configure the binder to use it.

**EDIT**

The `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` has a property to enable converting `byte[]` headers to `String`.

```
/**
 * Set the headers to not perform any conversion on (except {@code String} to
 * {@code byte[]} for outbound). Inbound headers that match will be mapped as
 * {@code byte[]} unless the corresponding boolean in the map value is true,
 * in which case it will be mapped as a String.
 * @param rawMappedHeaders the header names to not convert and
 * @since 2.2.5
 * @see #setCharset(Charset)
 * @see #setMapAllStringsOut(boolean)
 */
public void setRawMappedHeaders(Map<String, Boolean> rawMappedHeaders) {
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, this worked like a charm!.
On a different note, Posted the question in SO and Github with different intention, to get attention from 2 different userbase. While I agree that some users like yourself is overlapping across both platforms. From SO, I was expecting a work around from a fellow developer. From GitHub, I was expecting more authentic answer or initiate a conversation for making the platform better or a potential contribution. That being said, I should have made my intention clear. Sorry

Comment: That's a fair point. We just get a bit irked when we get the same question in multiple places - some people also ask on Gitter too! For general questions how do I do this or that, we prefer Gitter for simple questions; when code/config is needed we prefer SO; with GitHub, if you had phrased it more like. "Enhancement request - I need a mechanism for more control over header mapping", I wouldn't have reacted the same way and would have replied with the mechanism that already exists. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Its all good Gary. Thanks for your contributions to the opensource world. BTW, I ended up extending your own DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper and just overrode fromHeaders() method

Comment: any code example for this on how to consume a Kafka Header of <String, Object> and convert to <String, String> ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean and you shouldn't ask new questions in comments on old answers; ask a new question and provide more details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is an implementation for what you just described above. Any Java code example on how to read Headers that are String, byte[] and convert them to String, String for Spring Cloud Stream Kafka to consume. Right now when I pick a message up, the value is of type byte[]

Comment: You can add the desired header name to the `rawMappedHeaders` Map property with the value `Boolean.TRUE` which means convert a header with that name to a String using a charset (defaults to UTF-8).

Comment: Thanks Gary. Can I do this via application.yml or should I create a bean and inject?

Comment: The mapper has to be defined as a bean and then you put the bean name in the yml `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName`. We have an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/585) to add it to the yml.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove the "spring_json_header_types" header:

1. extending DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper:

   ```
   package com.config.streams;    
   import org.apache.kafka.common.header.Headers;
   import org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper;
   import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;

   public class KafkaHeaderMapperNoSpringHeader extends DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper {

       @Override
       public void fromHeaders(MessageHeaders headers, Headers target) {
           super.fromHeaders(headers, target);
           target.remove("spring_json_header_types");
       }

   }
   ```
2. instantiating the bean:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class StreamsConfiguration {

          @Bean
          public KafkaHeaderMapper kafkaHeaderMapperNoSpringHeader() {
              return new KafkaHeaderMapperNoSpringHeader();
          } ...
   ```
3. and adding the following property in the application.properties:

   *spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName = kafkaHeaderMapperNoSpringHeader*